# User action for send oush notifications in firebase on android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is possible to send push notifications with firebase without using the console,I mean can I send a push notifications when some user makes some action in the app?

Answer (score 1):

> Is possible to send push notifications with firebase without using the
>   console

Yes you can use Firebase API

> I mean can I send a push notifications when some user makes some
>   action in the app?

You can subscribe to a topic when user makes some action in the app

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("news");
```

and send a notification from Firebase web console or use Firebase API to all topic subscribers.

Answer (score 1):

You can [send a message to a topic from the Firebase Cloud Messaging API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging#build_send_requests).

But this requires the use of your FCM server key, which means it should only be done from an app server. You should never embed your server key in the client-side app. This means that direct device-to-device notifications are not possible at the moment, you will always need an app server for that.

For a tutorial explaining one possible scenario, see: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html